# How to change a specific control panel setting when HDMI cable is plugged in?

Tags: windows, hdmi, lid

I want to make it so when I plug a second display into my laptop it changes the control panel setting that sleeps the PC when I shut the lid of the laptop. I want to have the setting turn back on however when the second display is no longer plugged in.

Answer (score 1):

Control Panel settings do not work in reverse.

In Control Panel, you set what you want to happen for an action (e.g. lid close, then sleep).

But Control Panel cannot relate Monitor plugged in to Lid close.

So you cannot do what you want via the Monitor action.

**Workaround:**

For sleep, you should be able to set Lid Close to Nothing, and set the Sleep Button (keyboard) to sleep.

Press the button to sleep, and then close the lid (do nothing).

I think the workaround should work fine for you.